# failing to render in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

Sometimes when I open a page, it has blank only, but when I refresh the page or the browser, the page can be rendered.

I want to know why it happened and how the problem happened so much!

Comment: You'll need to post sample code.

Comment: Check with firebug whether there is any error or not!

Answer (score 0):

Some code from your HTML could be helpful but this is what I'm thinking:

It may have something to do with the order in which you are including your JS files.  Be sure to load ext-base.js then ext-all.js before your own javascripts.  You will then need to load any other resources required for your layout to render.

I'm thinking that on the first (blank) load, it fails to load the screen because of the resources are not coming in at the right time.  When you reload the page, the scripts load because they have already been cached by the browser.